# How to merge a PDF into another PDF in MS Access (automatically)?

Tags: ms-access, pdf, merge, windows-10

I am using Access 2010 and normally I've been using Leban's code for merging PDFs together automatically (in absence of more expensive drivers/software) and it's been working fine up until recently, when on a newer 64 bit Windows 10 operating system for whatever reason the usual LoadLibrary() function does not pick up DynaPDF.dll (regardless of where I place it).

So I need to find another way to merge PDFs together through Access but so far I haven't found anything. Am I out of luck without paying money for something?

Comment: Is Access also 64 bit? If not, Windows x64 shouldn't matter.

Comment: I have relied on the intrinsic Acrobat library to merge PDF files. Unfortunately, I think it requires installation of at least Adobe Acrobat Standard for the Adobe Acrobat Type x.0 Library to be available in Access.

Comment: Did you (re-) register your dll file?

Comment: Most versions of windows been x64 bits for a long time. However, the most common office install is still x32. Lebans code ONLY works with office x32 (the bit size of windows + os does NOT matter). So your code should work just fine, but only if you using office x32 which is still recommended. If you use office x64, then you can't use Lebans code since it is compiled for x32 - there is not a x64 bit version. While "some" companies are adopting office x64, I would suggest you stick to office x32, even on windows x64 (and this is the common recommend setup right now).

Comment: Well whatever the difference, the code works when I access it from my Windows 7 Citrix instance but not from the Windows 10 instance -- not sure if the Access versions are different but I can only work with what I can work with. I can't go installing new versions since I don't control that. The LoadLibrary() call always returns false no matter where I point it.

Comment: @June7 Does it work with Standard or Pro?

Comment: I had Pro but what I've read says Standard is minimum required.